# Broken pipe connecting to AWS with Fabric

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, fabric

I've been using [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) to run setup commands on an EC2 instance during some automated unittests. These tests ran fine for months, and then a few days ago, suddenly started  failing with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 207, in test_setup
    run('./setup_server')
  File "/usr/local/myproject/src/buildbot/worker3/myproject_runtests/build/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 682, in host_prompting_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/src/buildbot/worker3/myproject_runtests/build/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 1091, in run
    shell_escape=shell_escape, capture_buffer_size=capture_buffer_size,
  File "/usr/local/myproject/src/buildbot/worker3/myproject_runtests/build/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 934, in _run_command
    capture_buffer_size=capture_buffer_size)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/src/buildbot/worker3/myproject_runtests/build/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 816, in _execute
    worker.raise_if_needed()
  File "/usr/local/myproject/src/buildbot/worker3/myproject_runtests/build/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/thread_handling.py", line 26, in raise_if_needed
    six.reraise(e[0], e[1], e[2])
  File "/usr/local/myproject/src/buildbot/worker3/myproject_runtests/build/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/thread_handling.py", line 13, in wrapper
    callable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/src/buildbot/worker3/myproject_runtests/build/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/io.py", line 31, in output_loop
    OutputLooper(*args, **kwargs).loop()
  File "/usr/local/myproject/src/buildbot/worker3/myproject_runtests/build/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/io.py", line 152, in loop
    self._flush(end_of_line + "\n")
  File "/usr/local/myproject/src/buildbot/worker3/myproject_runtests/build/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/io.py", line 57, in _flush
    self.stream.flush()
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

The command I'm running is a `pip install -r requirements.txt`, and it appears to run just fine. If I run the test locally, it completes without error. However, it now fails half-way through when run on AWS every time.

What would cause this? Since it's an IOError, and these can be caused by virtually any kind of minor network interruption, I'm not sure how to diagnose it. If Fabric lost connection temporarily, that would explain it, but it wouldn't explain why it's repeatable. I've re-run this script several dozen times, and it fails each time after initially connecting to the EC2 instance perfectly.

Is there some sort of configuration in Fabric I can change to improve connection error handling?

Comment: Could you run every command manually and successfully on EC2 instance?

Comment: Can you please post a MCVE (i.e the code that you are trying to execute) for us to help?

Comment: @Sraw Yes, when I run my fabric script locally, it completes fine. When I run it from Buildbot, my CI server, it appears to run fine at first, and then a `pip install requirements.txt` step fails halfway through with this error.

Comment: @2ps, Unfortunately, no. I wish I could.